# Docker /bin/sh: 1: ng: not found (Angular)

Tags: angular, docker

I am trying to build a docker image for an Angular app but it crashes on `RUN ng build --prod` and I get the following error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: ng: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c ng build --prod' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:13.3.0 AS compile-image
RUN npm install -g yarn
WORKDIR /opt/ng 
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn
RUN yarn install
COPY . ./ 
RUN ng build --prod
FROM nginx
COPY docker/nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=compile-image /opt/ng/dist/dashboard /usr/share/nginx/html
CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

I have no previous experience with docker, so sorry if this is a stupid question.

Comment: Where is this `ng` command supposed to come from? (For example, should `yarn install` be creating it? If so, _where_ do you expect `yarn install` to be creating it, which is to say, where does it put the file?)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You might have the Angular CLI installed as a global package when you do normal development, making the `ng` command available everywhere. It isn’t installed globally in the Docker container, and rather than installing it globally you should use the local version directly:

```
RUN node_modules/.bin/ng build --prod
```

Comment: The question is why we can't install angular cli as a global package inside a docker container ? ie RUN npm i -g @angular/cli

Comment: @soung: You can, there’s just no need. Waste of a layer.

Comment: Ok I see, another  solution would be adding node_modules/.bin/ in path env variable. Something like RUN ENV PATH="node_modules/.bin:$PATH"

Comment: @soung: That works, but make sure to add the full absolute path. Environment variables are inherited unchanged, so any child processes in a different working directory could look in unintended (and maybe even dangerous) places.